# eregi replace replacement

Tags: php, pcre, posix-ere

since eregi replace was deprecated on version 5.3 i want to make my program compatible with new version of php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php

so, i'm trying to use preg_replace like this

```
preg_replace(",",'','20,000.00');
```

but come with error

i'm familiar with `eregi_replace(',','','20,000.00');` i'm not familiar with regex expression. what is the best replacement for **eregi_replace**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preg_replace needs delimiters

```
$value = '20,000.00';    
$value = preg_replace("/,/",'',$value);    
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(",",'','20,000.00');
```

Comment: @apis17 this is not "also" works. this is the difference between string functions and regular expressions you'd better understand.